# VIM: Using custom functions as parameters for shell

Tags: shell, vim

I have the following code in a vim file that it's auto sourced when editing php files. But I can't make it work.

```
"PHP config
if !exists("g:addPath")
  let g:addPath = 1
  let $PATH=$PATH.';C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox'
endif 

function! MakeThisUrl()
  let s:url='http://localhost/'
  let s:url=s:url. expand('%')
  return s:url
endfunction

function! MakeCustomUrl()
  let s:url='http://localhost/'
  let s:url=s:url. expand('%:p')
  return s:url
endfunction


map <F9>  :w<CR>:!firefox -new-tab MakeThisUrl()<CR>
map <F10>  :!firefox -new-tab call MakeCustomUrl()
imap <F9>  <Esc>:w<CR>:!firefox -new-tab MakeThisUrl()<CR><CR>
imap <F10>  <Esc>:!firefox -new-tab call MakeCustomUrl()
```

The idea is to make vim to auto generate the proper URL, so I can test the code just by presing F9. However, I can't make it execute MakeThisUrl() and all I get its

```
:!firefox -new-tab MakeThisUrl() <CR><CR>
```

instead of

```
:!firefox -new-tab http://localhost/filename.php <CR><CR>
```

Any ideas on how to make it work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I can't make it execute MakeThisUrl() and all I get its
>   :!firefox -new-tab MakeThisUrl()

This doesn't work, because the command is executed as if typed. Try this instead:

```
map <F9>  :up<CR>:execute ":!firefox -new-tab ".MakeThisUrl()<CR>
```

The major change: use of the [`:execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute) which executes command resulting from the evaluation of the expression. Expression evaluation is when functions are called. Here its result is concatenated with the `":!firefox -new-tab "` and it is gets executed as an `Ex` command (the commands starting with the `:`; for the `:execute` the leading `:` is optional).

P.S. The minor change/nitpick: instead of `:w` use [`:up`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:update) (or `:update`) which writes the buffer only if it is modified.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked just fine. Didn't thougt of using execute to generate the command. Thanks for the `update` hint, I'll apply it on other files I have on `au`